# decrypt str in dictionary using bytes and fernet

Tags: json, encryption, byte

I am trying to decrypt encrypted strs that are inside of a dictionary. To do this, the values must first be encoded, then the data can be decrypted and then decoded. I am struggling to encode the values without encoding the keys.

P.S: here is the printout for line 4:
b'{"pid": 6, "parent_first": "gAAAAABjAsAWbyxBsR804rVdMJ_Dzfj1s5s9GYVFSB2AJq3VSHTjH2V7lE4lt2gtO3LrhL6eKTm1qx153VO-g5xxWRb6mjXqvQ==", "parent_last": "gAAAAABjAsAWgiUupGo06d-tLY3WHgpfu5g0y55DjCPXdx4G2hIkEw50e3HAyi_r6z5NBHnJkevR8WkAy-2mhjvhUFRUk7Le8Q==", "email": "gAAAAABjAsAWAOTCver2_4bsBfrDA8SIdrykIH8Jojkd5100HT9y2Yz6ZnbZfYBqOYgwcKEquFhRGRZtey0A1Mdu12GxSHD3OdN8zb1DlLF0cP6O9tZEHGc=", "password": "f58a1612e9af7b5ee7e2141730f9a680f94765ad082918d489be42bde5d9ab23", "username": "9e7bd6851718b496e3c9cb0db480cbb8b87cf0455a7d627658906158357849b1"}'

```
for user in query:
    dict = user.to_dict()
    res_bytes = json.dumps(dict).encode('utf-8')
    print(res_bytes)
    res_bytes['parent_first'] = decrypt(res_bytes['parent_first'.encode('utf-8')])
    res_bytes['parent_last'] = decrypt(res_bytes['parent_last'.encode('utf-8')])
    res_bytes['email'] = decrypt(res_bytes['email'.encode('utf-8')])
    res_bytes['username'] = decrypt(res_bytes['username'.encode('utf-8')])
    dict = json.loads(res_bytes)
    print(dict)
```

this gives an error of byte indices must be integers or slices, not bytes

Answer (score 0):

`res_bytes` contains a byte sequence, so trying to work with it as if it's a dictionary instance doesn't make sense and results in the error you're seeing.

Basically, there's no reason to use `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` in this code snippet.

Instead, try something like:

```py
for user in query:
    u = user.to_dict()
    u['parent_first'] = decrypt(u['parent_first'])
    u['parent_last'] = decrypt(u['parent_last'])
    u['email'] = decrypt(u['email'])
    u['username'] = decrypt(u['username'])
    print(u)
```

A few notes:

- Once you've converted `user` to a dictionary, proceed to use it as a dictionary.
- [`Fernet.decrypt()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.Fernet.decrypt) can take either a `str` or `bytes` as input, so no need to worry about encoding/decoding it.